# Showing online video in tv app with ExoPlayer

Tags: android, exoplayer

How to show online live stream video with ExoPlayer in an Android app?
If the site address does not have .MP4 extensions

Comment: Can you provide an example url and code on how you are implementing ExoPlayer and what errors you are seeing.

Comment: This is a url : ' http://live.irib.ir/frame/t/tv1# '

Comment: ExoPlayer doesn't play iFrames

Comment: What is the best way to play that?

Comment: Your best option if you can't get the embedded stream is a webview.

Comment: How does the URL address in WebView automatically play?

Comment: If you can play it on a webpage in a video tag or an iframe it will play in a webview.